# Django website : make the url adress unchangeable

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to get your advices in order to block the url modification by my clients.
For example, I have a client in my website and he will redirect to his own page after the log process.

His homepage url looks like : `http://localhost:8000/Compagny/id/` with `id` corresponding to the `Compagny1`.

For example : `http://localhost:8000/Compagny/1/` with `1` is the first Compagny
But, in the url bar, if my client writes : `http://localhost:8000/Compagny/2/` he will be redirected to Compagny2's homepage and I don't want this possibility.

My question is :

How I can implement some rules, functions, or anything else in order to set unchangeable the url adress ? Client couldn't change the url and see the homepage which make reference to another client ?

Thank you

EDIT :

This is my homepage view :

```
@login_required
def HomePage_Compagny(request, id) :

    compagny = get_object_or_404(Compagny, pk=id)
    intervention = CompagnyIntervention.objects.filter(Compagny__id=id).all()
    pointsajoutes = CompagnyAjout.objects.filter(Compagny__id=id).all()

    coefficient = CoefficientIntervention.objects.last()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form_ajout = ContratAjoutFormulaire(request.POST or None)

        if form_ajout.is_valid() :   

            #Several processes

            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://mywebsite/'+id)

    else:
        form_ajout = ContratAjoutFormulaire()


    context = {
        ...
    }

    return render(request, 'CompagnyHomePage.html', context)
```

My url for this part is : `url(r'^Compagny/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.Homepage_Compagny, name="Homepage"),`

Comment: just define the name directly in urls.py `url(r'mywebsite/csa$', view) `

Comment: @AvinashRaj But If I define directly the url name : `url(r'mywebsite/csa$', view)`, `url(r'mywebsite/aboproject$', sameview)`, .. client could change the url again and access to another homepage no ?

Comment: wait? is that your client can able to change your code?

Comment: You can't stop the user typing a different url in the browser. In the view you need to check that the user is allowed access. It would be easier to suggest how to do this if you show your view (or a simplified version of it).

Comment: @Alasdair but we write the company name directly on the url, so except for that particular company name all other urls like `mywebsite/blah` should return 404.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not the client can't change the code, but he can modify the url adress and get the homepage from another compagny.

Comment: @Alasdair I will show you a simplified version of my view in my question ;)

Comment: How is the `Compagny` model related to the user model?

Comment: There is not relation up to now between `Compagny` and user. I don't implement this relation yet because I just have one user : Admin user.

Comment: You can't restrict access unless you have a login for each customer and link the customer and `Compagny` model. The only other option is to use obscure URLs that can't be guessed e.g. `/Compagny/f48c1d08-09b3-47ce-a90c-31e5559c1092/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent the user from typing a url in their browser. Instead, you should restrict access in the view, and return 404 if the user is not allowed to access that company.

For example, if the `Compagny` has a foreign key to `User`, then you could do:

```
@login_required
def HomePage_Compagny(request, id) :

    compagny = get_object_or_404(Compagny, pk=id, user=request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to implement a new model `User` and make a relationship between User and Compagny right ?

Comment: No, `User` is [Django's user model or your custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) if you already defined one.

Comment: I have to create a `User model` because I used just the `User management` in Django Admin.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you use the Django admin, there is already a `User` model (or a custom user model), so you can use that.

Comment: I have some tables : `auth_user`, `auth_group`, ... But I have to modify user table in order to add a foreign key from `Compagny`

Comment: If you add `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` to your `Compagny` model, then you don't need to modify the user table. That would allow each `Compagny` to have one user. If you need to link multiple users to the same `Compagny`, you could create a `UserProfile` model with a one-to-one field to `User`.

Comment: Ok, I will try your answer et your advices :) Thank you very much

Comment: It works pretty well ! I have a last question : Is it possible to have 2 users for one Compagny in this model ? For example : `Admin` and `Compagny user` ?

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question, because it's quite different from the original problem.

Comment: Ok Alasdair. It's the first time I'm making this kind of things so I will ask a new question. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py file where you wrote the function for the page you should use `user=request.user` with this given you can apply multiple methods to block users from specific sites.

1. use the `if user.is_authenticated():` method in views.
2. give users a group and deny access to specific pages
3. check in the template if the current user is allowed to see the site

If a user visits a url you can redirect him to the main page or display a 404 or tell him that he does not have access rights for this site.

For Example in the template you can display an error message like:

```
{% if request.user == pageowner %} 
the site code

{%else%}

<h1>This is not your Site. Please Go back</h1>
{%endif%}
```

in the views.py function you would have to define a "pageowner" attribute where you define a user who "owns" or at least created that Page.

Comment: I read your answer, but I get a little problem with your comment. I have a generic template with changing data according to each Compagny. So I have for example : `{% if request.user == csa %} ` but the html will not display the same generic template for `aboproject` in same time

Comment: of course you are not supposed to hardcode the username Since not every user is called "csa" right? What you need to do is write a definition in you views.py function. `pageowner = compagny.created_by` and in the compagny model you should have a "created_by" attribute(you should have that anyway since its always interesting to know who created the page)